# Create Dataframe in Pandas - Out of memory error while reading Parquet files

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dask, parquet, vaex

I have a Windows 10 machine with 8 GB RAM and 5 cores.

I have created a parquet file compressed with gzip. The size of the file after compression is 137 MB.
When I am trying to read the parquet file through Pandas, dask and vaex, I am getting memory issues:

**Pandas** :

```
df = pd.read_parquet("C:\\files\\test.parquet")
OSError: Out of memory: realloc of size 3915749376 failed
```

**Dask**:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_parquet("C:\\files\\test.parquet").compute()
OSError: Out of memory: realloc of size 3915749376 failed
```

**Vaex**:

```
df = vaex.open("C:\\files\\test.parquet")
OSError: Out of memory: realloc of size 3915749376 failed
```

Since Pandas /Python is meant for efficiency and 137 mb file is below par size , are there any recommended ways to create efficient dataframes?  Libraries like Vaex, Dask claims to be very efficient.

Comment: The latest release of vaex (v4) has much improved, out of core support for parquet files. 
`pip install vaex==4.0.0` or `conda install -c conda-forge vaex==4`. I think that will solve many of your problems. If you go for this, make sure you do not use python 3.9 for the time-being.

Answer (score 2):

It is totally possible that a 137MB parquet file expands to 4GB in memory, due to efficient compression and encoding in parquet. You may have some options on load, please show your schema. Are you using fastparquet or pyarrow?

Since all of the engines you are trying to use are capable of loading one "row-group" at a time, I suppose you only have one row group, and so splitting won't work. You *could* load only a selection of columns to save memory, if this can accomplish your task (all the loaders support this).

Answer (score 1):

For single machine, I would recommend Vaex with HDF file format. The data resides on hard disk and thus you can use bigger data sets. There is a built-in [function](https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#I-have-a-massive-CSV-file-which-I-can-not-fit-all-into-memory-at-one-time.-How-do-I-convert-it-to-HDF5?) in vaex that will read and convert bigger csv file into hdf file format.

`df = vaex.from_csv('./my_data/my_big_file.csv', convert=True, chunk_size=5_000_000)`

Dask is optimized for distributed system. You read the big file in chunks and then scatter it among worker machines.

Comment: "Dask is optimized for distributed system" - untrue, see https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/single-machine.html

Comment: @mdurant I never said, dask doesn't support single machine. the point is does dask support out-of-core data loading on single machine?

Comment: yes, it does, that's what it was built for (distributed came later)

Comment: Can you please direct me to the relevant doc? because last time when I was trying to load a big csv file with dask; it crashed with low memory error; plus I couldn't perform operations like filtering etc that requires to work on whole data.

Comment: Sorry, that's a pretty vague description. There are *many* variables. You can post a question about your situation, if you like, or try any dask-dataframe tutorial.

Comment: To be specific, dask.read_csv('bigger_than_memory.csv').compute() gives memory error.

Comment: That would be loading the whole data into memory - you should be expecting that error.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are using the latest version of pyarrow. A few times updating has helped me.

`pip install -U pyarrow`

Answer (score 0):

`pip install pyarrow==0.15.0` worked for me.